# Nuxt3: pass data from page A to B with same level (no relation like child-parent)

Tags: vuejs3, nuxt3, event-bus, pass-data

iam try use plugins 'mitt' but it not work
plugins/mitt.client.js

```
import mitt from "mitt";
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  const emitter = mitt();
    nuxtApp.provide('bus', {
      $on: emitter.on,
      $emit: emitter.emit,
    })
  })
```

cart/index.vue

```
const handlePassData = ()=>{

  $bus.$emit('itemsToCheckout', 'hello')
  navigateTo('/checkout')
}
```

checkout/index.vue

```
onMounted(() => {
console.log($bus);
  $bus.$on('itemsToCheckout', (data)=>{
    itemsToCheckout.value = data
    console.log(data);
  })
});
```

i cannot receive data on checkout page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing you can do is to introduce state management with [Pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/introduction.html). It can be simply included into Nuxt with a [dedicated module](https://pinia.vuejs.org/ssr/nuxt.html).

In `/composables/useCart.js` you define the store:

```js
export const useCart = defineStore('cart', {
  state: () => ({ items: [] }),
  getters: {
    // items will be available as useCart().items out of the box
    // but here you can define additional logic - like compute the total price
  },
  actions: {
    // all methods to manipulate with cart's state 
    // (available as `this` within `actions` scope)
    addToCart(item) {
      this.items.push(item);
    },
  },
})
```

then it is available across whole app just via `useCart()` (thanks to Nuxt autoimports from `composables`) - first call of this method will initiate the store, then it holds persistent data until the page is refreshed or a special built-in `$reset()` function is called.

Comment: i have cart store use pinia, but in cart page, i want user can choose item to check out, not all item in cart so i want pass data selected from cart to checkout page

Comment: In Pinia you can have any data you want. So you can just introduce new element into `state` - lets call it `itemForCheckout` - in one component, you set it, when user picks it, and in the second component you read it.

Comment: ah, i see. tks you so much